# Код на Delphi: ошибка на TForm7

Tags: delphi

Есть такой код на Delphi. Не хочет работать, ругается на TForm7. Работаю в RAD Studio Embarcardero. В  чем проблема? Форма все та.

```
unit Unit7;

interface

uses
Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
Dialogs, StdCtrls, ADODB, DB, ExtCtrls, DBCtrls, Grids, DBGrids;

type
TForm7 = class(TForm)
DBGrid1: TDBGrid;
ADOConnection1: TADOConnection;
ADOTable1: TADOTable;
DBNavigator1: TDBNavigator;
DataSource1: TDataSource;
ADOQuery1: TADOQuery;
Edit1: TEdit;
Label1: TLabel;
Button1: TButton;
Label2: TLabel;
procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
private
{ Private declarations }
public
{ Public declarations }
end;

var
 Form7: TForm7;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm7.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
 var result:variant;
begin
result:=NAZ.Lookup ('N_PUNKT', Edit1.Text, 'N_PUNKT;BAL');
if VarType (result) = varNull then
ShowMessage ('Нет ' + Edit1.Text)
else
if VarType (result) = varEmpty then
  ShowMessage ('Поиск не произведен')
else
  if VarIsArray (result) then
    begin
        Label1.Caption:= result[0];
        Label2.Caption:= result[1];
    end;
end;
```

Comment: Приведите текст ошибки, выдаваемой средой.

Answer (score 3):

> RAD Studio Embarcardero

Будь здесь Всеволод Леонов, он бы вам башку оторвал, среда нызвается Embarcadero RAD Studio:).

Я почему-то думаю, что это копи-паста самого скверного качества: какой-то невтемный NAZ, бессмысленные названия котролов.

Т.к. ошибка у вас в самой первой строчке, то не плохо было бы проверить:

1. Как у вас называется форма?
2. Добавили ли вы этот метод к методам формы?
3. Проверьте, имеютя ли нужные модули в `uses`.
4. Проверьте, работает(компилируется) ли пустая форма с кнопкой и простым обработчиком(напр. `ShowMessage('Hello!')` ?)

Отдельное пожелание: скажите ошибку.

**UPD:**

TForm**7** навёл меня на мысль, что это не единственная форма ;-).И `NAZ` в используемых юнитах я не нашёл. Ошибку вы так и не сказали, однако, если это действительно не единственная форма, советую вам проверить конфликты имён.

Comment: Да пустая форма компилится с кнопкой и простым обработчиком.

Comment: копипаста, эт лекции преподши))

Comment: > копипаста, эт лекции преподши))

Тогда стоит спросить у преподши, что это за `NAZ`.